# I want to make a cannon ball sink slowly into the ground

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I want to make this giant cannon ball sink slowly into the ground.
[image]

I've attached a bone to the plane and animated it so it does this:
[image]

The problem is, I want other objects to fall into the hole after the cannon ball (like a diploma and a hat). After making the plane a passive rigid body object and the diploma and hat active, the active objects don't react to the ground plane's mesh deformation (even when I check all the animated/deform/deforming boxes in the passive object rigid body settings). Help!

[.blend on GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KQKP6-BZZMK6gd2f7YUZQQQNPkODT6_c)

Comment: have you tried dynamic paint, and it might be helpful if you could upload you .blend file

Comment: I have never heard of dynamic paint - to google! I'll add the blender file...